# String incode or format

Tags: android, url, jsoup

hi im trying to copy a link to android studio and the link should be:
[https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/ادهم/](https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85/)
and it gives me :
https://www.almaany.com/ar/name/%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85/

how can I deal with this ?

Comment: looks like it was encoded, it probably works the same

Answer (score 0):

I Resolve it with
 String Name= URLEncoder.encode("ادهم", "utf-8");